# Mock render props React Component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

Hi I'm trying to mock the following React component:

```
<Component content={data || {}}>
   {() => <ChildComponent/>}
 </Component>
```

I wrote the following mock in **mocks**

```
import React from 'react';

const ComponentToMock = () => <div>A mock</div>;
export default ComponentToMock;
```

Now inside my test file I wrote

```
    jest.mock('presentational/Component');
    it(`should render`, () => {
      let wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />);
      console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
```

and in the console I'm getting

```
<ComponentToMock content={1}>
  <undefined />
</ComponentToMock>
```

while I was expecting just

```
<div>A mock</div>
```

Can anyone help me to find what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that using mount instead of shallow calls the render method so inside my **mocks** I wrote:

```
const ComponentMock = props => {
  return props.content ? props.children() : null;
};
export default ComponentMock;`
```